# xgboost speed difference per API

Tags: classification, xgboost

How can it be that a `xgboost.cv` cross-validation operation where n-folds are evaluated is quicker than a single `XGBoostClassifier.fit(X,y)` of the xgboost.sklearn API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the answer: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/651 
the sklearn api uses `n_estimators= 100` as default whereas xgb.train is using `n_boost_rounds=10`

As both refer to the same parameter this could explain the huge difference.